# Override some modules in a checkstyle file

Tags: checkstyle

There is a checkstyle rules xml file that is published company-wide. Some of the rules in that file do not conform to standards deployed by our team.

I want to override certain checks by writing my custom-checkstyle.xml file, and in that, I want to mention my company-wide checkstyle file; in order to have the best of both worlds.

Is there a native way to do it? I do not have the luxury of using external plugins to realize my vision.

Answer (score 0):

As of Checkstyle 7.3, there is no include feature or anything similar. Instead, you will have to copy your company-wide checkstyle.xml, modify it, and use the modified copy in your team.

A word of caution: This may get you in trouble. They usually provide these company-wide files because they want the teams to conform to the central standard.